# Why is Link component from react-router-dom is not accepting className props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here's my `PageLink` component,

```
export const PageLink: React.FC<IProps> = ({ id, question, searchBy }) => {

  return (
    <Link to={{pathname: `results/${id}`, search: `?sortBy=${searchBy}`}} className={styles.PageLink}>
      {question}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

None of the styles that I've written under `PageLink` is applied to this component. (BTW, I'm using css modules for this).

Based on other answers in SO, I replaced `Link` with `NavLink` and it works fine.

So, I have 2 questions,

1. Why is Link component not accepting className props?

Based on [this issue page](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/5403) people are telling that it's not a bug.

2. Is there anything wrong with using `NavLink` instead of `Link` (for my use case)

Comment: It works fine, you may want to check your project settings or your CSS module configs.

Comment: Quote from the github link you provided: [Again, this isn't something with our library, but with your configuration or tooling. Something else is intercepting and filtering out the className prop](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/5403#issuecomment-378006707)

Comment: Both Link and NavLink has className and works fine.

Comment: I did the test on the latest Router. What's the version of your router?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",

Comment: yeah, mine is also latest

Comment: I used the same version, here is my test, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b6r9rv?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: post `PageLink` styles. Also, check the developer tools whether your styles are overridden by something else.

Comment: I just restarted the server and it works with Link as well

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I just restarted my server and it just works with `Link` as well. I suspect that there's something funny going on with ts compiler. What's even strange is, I noticed many people asking the same question in different forums.